# Git Revert Error Message?

Tags: git, git-revert

While trying to revert a commit I made to my repository of my .emacs.d folder I get the following message:

```
haziz@haziz> git revert 7fe3f

error: could not revert 7fe3f0b... .emacs.d contents from ubuntu hp 15
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

What I am trying to do is reverse changes I made to my init.el file and have followed with another commit which I am trying to reverse. I would prefer to revert rather than reset --hard since as far as I know the latter completely erases the most recent commit. I would like to create a new commit so that I can possibly "revert" the revert.

In other words what I am trying to do is this

```
Git Commits [A]...[B]
```

would be reverted to

```
Git Commits [A]...[B]...[A']
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I tried doing a diff/merge as best as I could then another commit but then it still gives me this new error message:

```
haziz@haziz> git revert 7fe3f0ba3182b591f11c0b59e006dc6c990b7470

fatal: Your local changes would be overwritten by revert.
Please, commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
```

How do I tell it to ignore (but not delete) unstaged files, without resorting to a .gitigore file. I frankly don't care about most of the unstaged files which are emacs temp files etc.

Comment: Git is telling you what to do: resolve the conflict

Comment: `git status` will tell you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Q.** What conflict?

The conflict from merging the *reverse patch* of that revision, when later revisions changed the same lines of code: *a merge conflict*

> **Edit** If you are reverting the *latest* commit, this means that you had local changes (refer to `git status`). Don't forget that you can have *staged* and *unstaged* local changes. To easily see all local changes, use
>
> ```
>    git diff HEAD
> ```

You should just open up the unmerged file (`git status`) to see the conflicted file(s). You'll see the `<<<<`, `=====`, `>>>>>` conflict markers soon enough.

You can use

```
git mergetool
```

to resolve the conflicts with more user-friendly tools like Meld, KDiff3, Gvim etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a confusion between untracked files and unstaged files.

- Untracked files are unknown to Git, you never `git add`ed them (i.e. `git status` will show them in the `Untracked files:` section).
- Unstaged files are tracked files which have local changes, which you did not stage for commit (i.e. `git status` will show them in the `Changes not staged for commit:` section). These changes will be included in the next commit if you run `git commit -a`, but not if you run `git commit` without `-a`.

It does not make sense to tell git to ignore unstaged changes: the changes are there, and they touch files that Git cares about.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here because a `git revert HEAD~3` went horribly wrong (since the commit history was non-linear, and at least one of the past few commits was a merge, so Git didn't like that).

To go back to before I tried `git revert`, all you have to do is run this:

```sh
git revert --abort
```

That will undo all the reversions you made during the current git revert.